# Can I insert HtmlPartial in a ActionLInk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, actionlink

I have a partial view the returns an HTML5 video tag.  I want to make it so the user can click on the video and MVC will invoke a custom action.

I tried this

```
@Html.ActionLink( Html.Partial("_MediaClipPreview", clip), "Details");
```

but it won't compile as it says that my View does not have the right method: ("Park" is my Model class)

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MvcTest.Models.Park>' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

What is the correct way to wrap an action link around a partial view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionLink` only accepts text.
To add HTML, you need to use a regular `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(...)">...</a>
```